# Best way to transition from PHP to JavaScript(AngularJS, NodeJS, etc...)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, node.js, meteor

I'm currently a PHP Developer, and I absolutely love Laravel. However, even though Laravel is an excellent and powerful framework I feel as though I need to stay up to date on technologies and languages to deliver the absolute best. Which brings me to my main question, what would be the best way to transition(I Don't wish to just drop PHP, but shift my main focus) to JavaScript. Specifically, Node.JS, Angular, Meteor, etc...

The syntax of JavaScript is what really throws me off, does anyone know of a very well laid out tutorial series(Paid or Free) that I could learn from. I'm sure once I get past the learning curve I'll find it much easier. However getting past the curve is where I'm currently at, and struggling.

Thanks,
Bran

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS
https://www.udemy.com/understand-javascript/

Comment: I'd really recommend https://egghead.io/

Comment: You can still use PHP + laravel to create backend RESTful API and Angular (or any other js framework) for the fronted.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-time-tracker-with-laravel-5-and-angularjs-part-1
https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-and-angular

Comment: Did you end up on following a good stack similar to Laravel but in node.js format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Angularjs and the MEAN Stack**

There is a great set of tutorials for Angularjs on code school [here](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/).
I used them to learn the basics but in reality the best way to learn is to build a project you're passionate about.

For myself I learned how to use Ionic for mobile development, [here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/Scripto5000) is my open source code for that (Ionic is built on Angularjs).

Another great way to learn is to follow the Microsoft MEAN Stack video that they made about 6 months ago [here](https://youtu.be/Jh0er2pRcq8) it is. They do a full MEAN Stack project thats really easy to follow along with.

**Conclution**

To learn any new tech build build build, its the only way to discover more. Good luck